# AngularJs Group And Fill Comboboxes

Tags: json, angularjs, filtering, grouping

I have a Json data like this;

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

[{"Kod":16105,"TapuKod":9469416,"ParselNo":"48","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16106,"TapuKod":9469417,"ParselNo":"49","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16107,"TapuKod":9469187,"ParselNo":"5","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16108,"TapuKod":9469418,"ParselNo":"50","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16109,"TapuKod":9469426,"ParselNo":"51","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16110,"TapuKod":9469610,"ParselNo":"53","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16111,"TapuKod":9469615,"ParselNo":"54","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16112,"TapuKod":9469188,"ParselNo":"6","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16113,"TapuKod":9469189,"ParselNo":"7","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16114,"TapuKod":9469190,"ParselNo":"8","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16115,"TapuKod":9469191,"ParselNo":"9","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16116,"TapuKod":9468741,"ParselNo":"2","AdaNo":"126","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16117,"TapuKod":9468742,"ParselNo":"1","AdaNo":"127","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16118,"TapuKod":9468745,"ParselNo":"1","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16119,"TapuKod":9468748,"ParselNo":"2","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16120,"TapuKod":9468933,"ParselNo":"3","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16121,"TapuKod":9623908,"ParselNo":"4","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16122,"TapuKod":9623909,"ParselNo":"5","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16123,"TapuKod":9468950,"ParselNo":"6","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16124,"TapuKod":9695996,"ParselNo":"7","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16125,"TapuKod":9693613,"ParselNo":"1","AdaNo":"129","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16126,"TapuKod":9470332,"ParselNo":"1","AdaNo":"130","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16127,"TapuKod":9468983,"ParselNo":"10","AdaNo":"130","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},]

And have 2 Comboboxes like this;

[Here](http://hizliresim.com/JYRLGn)

I want to fill AdaNo ComboBox with AdaNo but do not want repeating same no. Then when i select any AdaNo it'll fill ParselNo combobox with parselNo which AdaNo=selectedAdaNo.

My ApiController:

```
 public string GetParselFromMahalleKod(int id)
    {


        List<TapuParselModel> parselList = TapuModule.GetParselListFromMahalleTapuKod(id);



        string jsonResult = SConvert.SerializeJSON(parselList);
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

in  tapuController.js;

```
 $scope.getParsels = function () {
        TapuParselApi.all($scope.selectedMahalle).success(function (response) {
            $scope.Parseller = angular.fromJson(response);
        })
```

and index like this;

```
 <div>
            Ada No:<select data-ng-model="adaNo">
                <option value="{{parsel.AdaNo}}" data-ng-repeat="parsel in Parseller">{{parsel.AdaNo}}</option>
            </select>
            Parsel No:<select data-ng-model="parselNo">
                <option value="{{parsel.ParselNo}}" data-ng-repeat="parsel in Parseller">{{parsel.ParselNo}}</option>
            </select>
            <button data-ng-click="downloadZeminsFromZeminArg()">Sorgula</button>
        </div>
```

Can i do that with one Json? 
Note: i'm using angularJs. So maybe there is a method in angular :)

What should i do?

Comment: Have you written any code so far?

Comment: Hi i edit my post with codes. Ty .

Comment: Please see the working code below, you might find your solution here.
Let me know if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the working code below, you might find your solution here.

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Ada No:</td>
            <td>
                <select ng-model="AdaNos" ng-options="item.AdaNo for item in items | unique:'AdaNo'">
                </select>               
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Parsel No:</td>
            <td>
                <select ng-model="ParselNos" ng-options="item.ParselNo for item in items | filter:AdaNos.AdaNo:true" | unique:'ParselNo'>
                </select>               
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>

    <script>

        var app = angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
            var data = [{"Kod":16105,"TapuKod":9469416,"ParselNo":"48","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16106,"TapuKod":9469417,"ParselNo":"49","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16107,"TapuKod":9469187,"ParselNo":"5","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16108,"TapuKod":9469418,"ParselNo":"50","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16109,"TapuKod":9469426,"ParselNo":"51","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16110,"TapuKod":9469610,"ParselNo":"53","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16111,"TapuKod":9469615,"ParselNo":"54","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16112,"TapuKod":9469188,"ParselNo":"6","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16113,"TapuKod":9469189,"ParselNo":"7","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16114,"TapuKod":9469190,"ParselNo":"8","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16115,"TapuKod":9469191,"ParselNo":"9","AdaNo":"125","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16116,"TapuKod":9468741,"ParselNo":"2","AdaNo":"126","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16117,"TapuKod":9468742,"ParselNo":"1","AdaNo":"127","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16118,"TapuKod":9468745,"ParselNo":"1","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16119,"TapuKod":9468748,"ParselNo":"2","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16120,"TapuKod":9468933,"ParselNo":"3","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16121,"TapuKod":9623908,"ParselNo":"4","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16122,"TapuKod":9623909,"ParselNo":"5","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16123,"TapuKod":9468950,"ParselNo":"6","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16124,"TapuKod":9695996,"ParselNo":"7","AdaNo":"128","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16125,"TapuKod":9693613,"ParselNo":"1","AdaNo":"129","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16126,"TapuKod":9470332,"ParselNo":"1","AdaNo":"130","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},{"Kod":16127,"TapuKod":9468983,"ParselNo":"10","AdaNo":"130","MahalleId":146436,"Record":null,"RecordDate":null,"Edit":null,"EditDate":null},]
            $scope.items = data;
        });

        app.filter('unique', function() {
           return function(collection, keyname) {
              var output = [], 
                  keys = [];

              angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
                  var key = item[keyname];
                  if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                      keys.push(key);
                      output.push(item);
                  }
              });

              return output;
           };
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```